# George Costanza took coin (In IBIZA) from the hat.

Tags: probability, independence

> In hat has two coins look identical, but one of them normal (probability "tree" 
>   0.5 And a fake one (probability "tree" 0.25).
>
> George Costanza took single coin from the hat.
>
> Define "A" - throw 1 coin and see "tree".
>
> Define "B" - throw 2 coins (the same coin) and the see 2 "trees".
>
> 1. A and B are independent?
> 2. Given the coin normal, A and B are independent?

**I thought about it this way:**

1.
$$P(A)=0.5*0.5+0.5*0.25=0.375 $$
$$P(B)=0.5*0.5*0.5+0.5*0.25*0.25=0.15625$$
$$P(A\cap B)=P(B)=0.15625$$
So:
$$P(A\cap B)\neq P(A)*P(B)$$

2.
$$P(A|NormalCoin)=0.5 $$
$$P(B|NormalCoin)=0.5*0.5=0.25$$
$$P(A\cap B|NormalCoin)=P(B|NormalCoin)=0.25$$
So:
$$P(A\cap B|NormalCoin)\neq P(A|NormalCoin)*P(B|NormalCoin)$$

Where is my mistake?
Thank you!

Comment: Why should you have a mistake?

Comment: The lecturer post solutions where the second part is independent